# What are the Visual Studio Analyzers and why mine are in warning status?

Tags: identityserver4, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I just updated my IdentityServer4 from Core 2.2 to Core 3.1. I did some code change to replace some line because a new MVC endpoint system. My project build, start, but something wrong happen.

In all this I also would like to understand what are these analyzers and why, after changing the project target from Core 2.2 to 3.1 I have now this orange warning icon? Where can I get more information about this warning and what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: I'm also still stuck with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318190/196526 related to same project.